# Reference to 'CMTime' is ambiguous

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to integrate Paypal SDK Sample into my App and I'm importing the necessary frameworks but I'm getting this error.

I'm using swift and I have a bridge header.

I think the errors are related to some settings about path's or bridge header because they are inside the frameworks and i havent touch them.

[image]

**Frameworks**:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
After Delete one CoreMedia Reference, I have now 200 errors for "Apple Match-O Linker Error"

[image]

Comment: Did you import CoreMedia ?

Comment: Yes (Updated post with framework list.)

Comment: You imported CoreMedia twice. What happens, if you remove one reference?

Comment: Thats right. I have deleted one reference and now i have 200 errors but they sound like the same: `Apple Match-O Linker Error`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to enable "Link Frameworks Automatically" in the build settings of your project? This will make the manual linking obsolete and possibly solve the issue.

Comment: It is turned on =/ This Paypal integration is driving me crazy